# Plugin for IntelliJ or Eclipse to draw method parameters in different colors?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

When i code, i sometimes mistake one parameter for another.

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data);
```

In this example, requestCode and resultCode are similar.

Is there an IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ) plugin that will draw parameters names in different colors, possibly with a background color as well?

This would be a time saver in many cases when reading code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with IntelliJ IDEA. For that you can enable [Semantic Highlighting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#semantic-highlighting).
Go to `Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults`, select `semantic highlighting` and tick checkbox.

[image]

Comment: +1. Its a good start. Unfortunately it uses the colors list for all variables. Its not like all FIRST parameters of every method will be Color#1. I did 5 bright Yellow,Green, Red, Purple, Blue.. and i have 2 green parameters in one method definition?!? Not very consistent.

Comment: after a day of use.. its a big improvement. I noticed the color is dependant on the variable name....by tweaking the colors scheme, i got an acceptable result for the parameter names resultCode, requestCode